# Is it possible to concurrently download a single file without range requests?

Tags: http, go, concurrency, http-headers

With HTTP/1.1 Ranged Requests there is a non-zero chance of corruption. Various transparent proxies usually used by ISPs can mangle the requests and thereafter return junk.

Also, not all servers support ranged requests and content length headers.

Is there a KISS way to concurrently download a file using GO without using these tricks?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a KISS way to concurrently download a file using GO without using these tricks?

No, there isn't. But this is not related to Go, this is a plain fact of how HTTP works. If you do not want to use range headers you cannot download just "the first" and "the second" half of a request.

Not only is there no "KISS way", there is absolutely no way (*except* by using the appropriate tools like range request).

Answer (score 1):

One possible method (depending on exactly how you interpret "concurrently") would be something like the code below. This will NOT allow you to set time-outs or a method through which you can monitor the progress of the download, but it will allow you to start a download, then read it at leisure later.

```
type download struct {
        err error
        r   io.ReadCloser
}

// Download a file in a goroutine, return a channel through which we can 
// read a download struct. The struct will either contain an error or 
// an io.ReadCloser through which we can read the file.
func download(url string) chan download {
        rv := make(chan download)
        go func() {
                resp, err := http.Get(url)
                if err != nil {
                         rv <- download{err: err}
                         return
                }
                switch {
                        resp.StatusCode == 200: 
                                // This can be made better, but is probably good 
                                // enough for an illustration
                                rv <- download{r: resp.Body}
                        default:
                                rv <- download{err: fmt.Errorf("HTTP GET gave status %s", resp.Status)
                }
        }()
        return rv
}
```